# Smooth out transition from static positioning to fixed positioning for sticky header?

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

Please take a look at the black navigation bar on this website I am building: http://thesemlab.com/

I am using jQuery Waypoints to change the positioning of this bar from static to fixed as you scroll down. The plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

My problem is if you scroll down fairly fast, it is not a very smooth transition. It will jump to the fixed positioning very fast, and it looks kind of janky.

I have tried using a CSS transition, but it does nothing! Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about the delay in scrolling past the stick point and sticking?

Comment: @Dude Not necessarily a delay. It's just very jumpy/jolty if you scroll fast enough. I'd rather it animate into place than jump into place. You guys are also free to tell me that it actually is fine.

Comment: Your talking about the delay. Animating it would be hard. Another option is to estimate the delay between updates and therefore estimate the next scroll position, and adjust before it happens.

Comment: Something to consider - that will help, but not completely dissolve the problem. When the element is changed to `position: fixed;` it is taken out of the stack. So, the elements under it will shift up. You can dynamically add some padding or some other way of inserting empty space to make up for the now missing element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, and there are lots of great examples online for this. Just in case someone comes across this, this one helped the most (https://remysharp.com/2017/06/29/smooth-scroll-with-sticky-nav). The main thing that helped was using "requestAnimationFrame" as a means of throttling the window.onscroll event to line up with the timing.

Below is a portion from some React code, but hopefully it gives more ideas.

// ... From within a functional component.

```
const [isFixed, setIsFixed] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const checkSetIsFixed = () => {
        const { y } = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (y <= 0) {
            setIsFixed(true);
        } else {
            setIsFixed(false);
        }
    }

    checkSetIsFixed();

    const onScroll = (e) => {
        requestAnimationFrame(checkSetIsFixed);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }
}, []);
```